# Calculate X amount of hrs ahead only counting 9-5 hrs

Tags: vb.net, time

I'm trying to get a quick ETA on some pre-determined values, 16 and 40. So for example, I need my code to quickly calculate an ETA on an item if it takes 16 hours, but only count the 9-5 (8) hours per day. Obviously I'd need to include the remaining hours of that day, which I have in the code snipped below. However I'm giving myself an ofly sore head trying to work out the best way to proceed with the code. Perhaps someone's got a good idea?

```
Dim TargetTime as Integer = 16
Dim currentHr As Integer = current.Hour
Dim TodaysRemainingHours As Integer = 0

If currentHr >= 9 AndAlso currentHr < 17 Then
    'Count remaining hours
    TodaysRemainingHours = (17- currentHr)
Else
    'Dont count today
    TodaysRemainingHours = 0
End If
```

My plan is:

- `TargetTime` - `TodaysRemainingHours` --- Gives the value to count
  to.
- Somehow calculate the hours based on 9-5 time spans only.
- Display `lblOutput` as: "ETA: 2pm 25/11/2016"

As you can see I know how to get the vaule I need to count to, but I need some help with firstly only counting the hours in each day from 9-5 and then returning the actual hour estimated. This isn't for anything profitable, it's a personal ETA program.

Comment: Since your time periods are multiples of 8 anyway, why don't you just count the number of "days" (ie, 2 or 5) from `Now`? If you start at 10:30 Tues, the ETA would be 10:30 Thur (or 10:30 Sun).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you topshot, your comment helped me work it out! The below code seems to work for me, I haven't identified any issues anyway. I had to make sure I wasn't counting the remaining hours in the current day if the time is past 5pm as well. Thank you.

```
        Dim TargetTime As Integer = 16
        Dim current As Datetime = DateTime.now 
        Dim currentHr As Integer = current.Hour
        Dim TodaysRemainingHours As Integer = 0

        If currentHr >= 9 AndAlso currentHr < 17 Then
            'Count remaining hours
            TodaysRemainingHours = (17 - currentHr)
        Else
            'Dont count today
            TodaysRemainingHours = 0
       End If

        If currentHr >= 9 AndAlso currentHr < 17 Then
        'Deduct todays hours from target time.
        TargetTime = (TargetTime - TodaysRemainingHours)
            'Display results
            MsgBox("ETA: " & Now.AddDays(TargetTime / 8))
            Else 
        'Skip todays hours and count from tomorrow morning at 9am
           Dim Tomorrow As  DateTime  = Today.AddDays(1)
           Dim TomorrowMorning As TimeSpan  = new TimeSpan(09, 00, 0)
            Tomorrow = Tomorrow.Date + TomorrowMorning
            'Display results
            MsgBox("ETA: " & Tomorrow.AddDays(TargetTime / 8))
            End If
```